# Swift Mailer - Getting odd header output

Tags: php, email, html-email, swiftmailer

I'm using Swift Mailer, but getting strange output, like so:

```
--_=_swift_v4_1421068500_80a78fd29e619e918b1c16e227289934500e81e7_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Website EnquiryName - nameEmail - example@example.comTelephone - te=
lephoneCompany - companyMessage - message

--_=_swift_v4_1421068500_80a78fd29e619e918b1c16e227289934500e81e7_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<h2>Website Enquiry</h2><p><strong>Name</strong> name</p><p><strong=
>Email</strong> example@example.com</p><p><strong>Telephone</strong> teleph=
one</p><p><strong>Company</strong> company</p><p><strong>Message</strong><b=
r />message</p>

--_=_swift_v4_1421068500_80a78fd29e619e918b1c16e227289934500e81e7_=_--
```

I am sending the email like so:

```
<?php

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' ) {
        die();
    }

    require_once '../swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

    $name       = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $email      = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $telephone  = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['telephone'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $company    = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['company'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    $message    = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));

    $to = "example@example.com"; // Removed for Stack Overflow demo.
    $subject = "Website Enquiry";

    $htmlMessage = "<h2>Website Enquiry</h2>";
    $htmlMessage .= "<p><strong>Name:</strong> "    . $name . "</p>";
    $htmlMessage .= "<p><strong>Email:</strong> " . $email . "</p>";
    $htmlMessage .= "<p><strong>Telephone:</strong> " . $telephone . "</p>";
    $htmlMessage .= "<p><strong>Company:</strong> " . $company . "</p>";
    $htmlMessage .= "<p><strong>Message:</strong><br />" . nl2br($message) . "</p>";

    $plainMessage = "Website Enquiry";
    $plainMessage .= "Name: " . $name . "";
    $plainMessage .= "Email: " . $email . "";
    $plainMessage .= "Telephone: " . $telephone . "";
    $plainMessage .= "Company: " . $company . "";
    $plainMessage .= "Message: " . $message . "";

    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom(array($email => $name))
        ->setTo(array($to => $subject))
        ->setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8")
        ->setBody($plainMessage, 'text/plain')
        ->addPart($htmlMessage, 'text/html');

    $result = $mailer->send($message);

?>
```

Preferably, I'd like to be sending HTML email, but I also want a plain text version. The code above seems okay in every way I can see, so not sure why I get the odd output of the email headers - possibly a character encoding issue?

Any help or direction greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I was using a DEV version - Swift-5.3.1-DEV (therefore possibly unstable).

After downgrading to the latest stable version Swift-5.3.0, I can now see this issue gone.

I did not use Composer to install the latest stable, but instead found myself using the ZIP from SwiftMailer's GitHub account. This version is the DEV version, so make sure you're getting the latest stable release: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/releases

Hope this helps.